# CLION: how to generate class diagrams from C++ source code

Tags: c++, clion, class-diagram

I have used Visual Studio successfully to generate class diagrams from C++ source code.
But I'm finding it hard to do the same in CLION. I used Settings / Preferences | Tools | Diagrams as per the JetBrains documentation, but it throws this error [CLION diagrams error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2qOd.jpg). "The current file or folder does not have any dependencies. Please try with another file or folder". But my source code is indeed having many dependencies.

How to generate class diagrams (UML or non UML) from C++ source in CLION?

Comment: You may find [BOUML](https://www.bouml.fr/) to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with CLion, but from what I've googled, it seems that CLion does not support C++ class diagrams: see this support question about [UML Diagrams in CLion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000645384-UML-Diagrams-in-CLion) and the corresponding feature request [OC-1038](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-1038) filed ten years ago, still not implemented.

However, CLion seems to have a basic UI allowing you to browse class hierarchy by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, as shown in this [CLion: A Modern C++ IDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqQCl3PAr7U&t=2503s) video by Dmitri Nesteruk from JetBrains at 41:43.